# "How do you like your bread made/done"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> How do you like your bread made?
>
> How do your like your bread done?

Does the first sentence have any meaning?

I'm confused what is better to go with the reply "Medium", "Well done”, etc.

Sometimes I hear that "How do you like your bread is made", is that my mishearing?

Can I say “How do you like your food is made?" (as street cooks in my country, who cook for customers as what they order)

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about *toasted* bread, in which case you would say "How do you like your toast done?", or "How do you like your toast?" It is unusual to hear "How do you like your bread done/made?"

Comment: What if I were a cook and I were asking my customer what I should do to their bread?

Comment: If you were baking bread for someone, you would probably say "How well done do you like your bread?" This seems to be more of a cultural question than a linguistic one. I am a Brit, and I have never had bread baked to order, and I imagine that the same is true for most of my fellow countrymen.

Comment: Are you sure it was bread and not meat? Because the only thing that has "doneness" is meat.

Comment: @Catija Not so. In BrE, you can talk about "well-done" (i.e. well-baked) bread. It is unusual, though, since most bread in the UK is shop-bought and highly standardised.

Comment: @Mick Meaning over baked? Or excellently baked? What are the options here? The only bread question I get at restaurants is what **kind** of bread/toast I want... white, rye, wheat, muffin, roll, etc... with a sandwich.

Comment: @Catija Quite. You are from the USA and I am a native Brit. Neither of us has any experience of being asked how well-baked we like our bread. We just get it as it comes. That may not be the case in other countries. I do occasionally bake my own bread, and I am very interested in how "well done" it is.

Comment: An English-speaking foreigner might not understand you. In the West, food is either *hand-made* or *machine-made*. It would be better to ask "How well-done [or well-cooked] would you like your food?"

Comment: If you want to get this question re-opened, I suggest that you edit the question to explain what you think the sentences might mean, or what you would want them to mean. Are we talking about making bread, or sandwiches, or toast, or something completely different?

Answer (score 3):

The instruction booklet for my bread maker offers three settings for how **well-done** the bread is: the options offered are **light**, **medium** and **dark**. I think that the best way to phrase the question without risk of misunderstanding would be

> How **well done** do you want your bread?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the food being made, and what the options are. Meat is generally cooked on a scale of “rare” to “medium” to “well-done”; eggs can be made in a number of ways (*poached, scrambled, over easy*, etc.); if I’m ordering a salad, someone might ask what kind of dressing I want.

I can’t think of a *general* question a vendor would ask that would apply to all kinds of food, such as, “How would you like your food made?” Instead, the cook would ask a *specific* question, such as:

- How would you like your meat cooked?
- How do you want your eggs?
- What kind of dressing do you want?
- What kind of bread do you want? [for a sandwich, or for toast]
- Do you want that dish deep fried, or sautéed?
- Do you want rice or beans with that?
- What do you want on your pizza?

Incidentally, my father likes his English muffins well-toasted. When he is eating breakfast at a restaurant, he’ll often tell the waiter, “Make sure those English muffins are well-done. I want them extra crisp.” So it is possible to use a term like “well done” with something toasted, but that’s an unusual case. And if he liked his English muffins lightly toasted, I don’t think he’d use the word “rare”.

Answer (score 2):

Both example sentences are valid but have a slightly different meaning. Using the word 'made' implies the actual making of a loaf of bread, from making the dough through baking it. The question "How do your like your bread done?" may also refer to making bread, or it may refer instead to some later part of food preparation, such as making a sandwich or toast with the bread.

The sentence "How do you like your bread is made" is not correct grammatically. You can either remove the 'is' to make "how do you like your bread made" or replace 'is' with 'to be' to make "How do you like your bread to be made?"

If you are asking about making bread into toast, you might ask "how well done do you want your toast" or "how dark do you want your toast".

Unfortunately, using the answers light, dark, raw or rare, medium, or well done to a question like this is situational; you will probably need to experiment with a given vendor or restaurant to determine what they think well done is unless they are able to point to an example and say this bread/toast/meat is well done so you can see what they mean when they say "this is well done".